# Trying to use data binding in DataTemplate.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently using a `DataTemplate` for a ComboBox to bind a Color to a Rectangle inside the ComboBoxItems.  Originally, I was just using the color to Fill the rectangle and the Stroke was black.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Color"}/>
</DataTemplate>
```

That's obviously a very simplified code snippet.  I create three different instances of the bound class using three different colors, and I see the three different colors just fine.

What I'm looking to do is take the Color and use it as the Stroke and for the Fill, lower the opacity to 25%.  This is what I tried doing:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RectangleStroke" Color="{Binding Color}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RectangleFill" Color="{Binding Color}" Opacity="0.25"/>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Rectangle Stroke="{StaticResource RectangleStroke}" Fill="{StaticResource RectangleFill}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, when I do that and again create three instances of the bound class with different colors, I actually see the first color three times.  For some reason, I think it has something to do with using `StaticResource`.  I tried using `DynamicResource` instead:

```
<Rectangle Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static RectangleStroke}}"/>
```

but it didn't like the `{x:Static RectangleStroke}` part.

If needed, I can provide more XAML and code-behind if my simplified snippets are unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to do with defining the `Resource` inside your `DataTemplate`. Try moving your `SolidColorBrush` resources to the `Window` scope.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RectangleStroke" Color="{Binding Color}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RectangleFill" Color="{Binding Color}" Opacity="0.25"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Or, better yet, just set the `fill` and `stroke` inside the `Rectangle` explicitly. There's no point of using a `Resource` if that `Resource` is only going to be used in that `Rectangle` only.

```
    <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Color}">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" Opacity="0.25" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks, I didn't know you could do the Rectangle.Fill like that.

Comment: Yep, you can access any control attribute like that.